# User Cannot see images in emails even though we can see them

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, email-studio

I have a client that cannot see the images in the emails that have been uploaded onto marketing cloud. When we try them on our systems they render, but the client is still insistent that he can't see them. Has anyone encountered this and have a solution?

Comment: Is it possible that their firewall is blocking the URL your image is hosted on?

Comment: Are you try to see it without session???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does come up from time to time. It is almost always due to the client setting up their new SFMC DNS correctly within the settings for *external* networks, but there also must be configuration done on settings for their *internal* network.

I've saved a good summary of the issue from support back in the day:

Images are not displaying internally because when your internal network tries to access the subdomain, it's looking for this internally as it thinks it is part of your domain, when it actually should be looking for this externally as ExactTarget is hosting it.

To resolve the problem with internal networks, you must perform one of the following options:

1. Setup the internal DNS like the external one by delegating the subdomain to Exacttarget.
2. Forward the subdomain to Exacttarget.
3. Instruct the network to use the external nameserver for the subdomain.
4. Create individual entries in the internal DNS to match the parts
   failing:

   - image.subdomain.domain.com IN CNAME
     images.exacttarget.com.edgesuite.net
   - click.subdomain.domain.com IN CNAME click.virt.exacttarget.com
   - view.subdomain.domain.com IN CNAME view.virt.exacttarget.com
   - bounce.subdomain.domain.com IN MX bounce.exacttarget.com
   - reply.subdomain.domain.com IN MX reply.exacttarget.com